# file 'lib' not found when installing rails 3.1 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rdoc, ri

I just installed rvm and then rails 3.1rc5 with:

```
gem install rails --pre
```

But I got some errors after "Installing ri documentation" and the RDoc documentation:

```
Successfully installed <bunch of things>
30 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for multi_json-1.0.3...
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-3.1.0.rc5...
Installing ri documentation for builder-3.0.0...
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README.rdoc, skipping
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.6.0...
Installing <tons more documentation>
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.0.rc5...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for multi_json-1.0.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for activesupport-3.1.0.rc5...
Installing RDoc documentation for builder-3.0.0...
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README, skipping
unable to convert "\xF1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for README.rdoc, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for i18n-0.6.0...
Installing <tons more documentation>
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.0.rc5...
file 'lib' not found
```

The README file issues don't seem to be a big deal, but the 'lib' file not found sounds a bit scary.. why is it doing that?  Some searching revealed others having this problem and fixing it with `gem install rdoc` and then re-running `gem install rails --pre`.  But that still gives the same `lib` file missing errors for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `rvm gemset install rails --pre`

Comment: it just says: "installing rails ...
rails  installed."  So I guess good in that I no longer get a lib file missing error, but doesn't look like it fixed anything.  Everything else seems to work...  what's the difference between `rvm gemset install` and the standard `gem install`?  I looked up the official docs and didn't even see an rvm gemset install command.

Comment: When you type `which ruby`, is the location in your `~/.rvm` folder?

Comment: I get this location: ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

Comment: Try running `gem install rails --pre --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Comment: What is the actual difference between *gem install* and *rvm gemset install*?

Answer (score 1):

I installed 3.1.0 on Windows (not rc8, but the final release), and got the "file 'lib' not found" error, installing both ri and RDoc.  When I type in 'which ruby', I see it installed in the c:/ruby192/bin directory.  I had to create a .rvm directory for myself -- it was not created as part of the install.

the --no-rdoc --no-ri worked, of course.  The --pre commands installed rc8 instead of the final release.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Installing RDoc fixed this problem for me. I had to do this in the gemset I was using.

```
rvm use rubyversion@gemset
gem install rdoc
```

After this I could install gems without the "*file 'lib' not found*" error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rails 3.0.9 on my Mac OS X Lion and the "rvm gemset install rails" trick solved it !

```
$ rvm gemset install rails
installing rails ...
rails  installed.
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.9
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is that really solving it?  I had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before, while my solution was this: try to use ruby 1.9.2-head instead of ruby 1.9.2-p290.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-head
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-head --default
```

And then, install rails 3.1 again.